# Windows 10 Photos taking 30 seconds to open

Tags: windows

Is it normal for the Windows 10 "Photos" application to take upwards of 30 seconds to open a small .png file? I just don't understand how Windows 98 opened photos faster than Windows 10. Is there any known fix for this issue? This is on a fresh install that is less than 2 weeks old.

Comment: How big is your overall photo library? Does it link to any online storage you may have?

Comment: There is maybe 10 photos on the entire system, other than system photos. All cloud activity is disabled

Comment: Then maybe it's trying & failing to contact something & waiting for timeout. There isn't enough info to guess much else. You might have 4GB RAM, a rusty old HD & 57 Chrome tabs open, which would explain it perfectly.

Comment: I have 22 GB of ram, Intel i7, and this occurs with no other processes open. In addition, Windows 1998 on a crusty old HDD opened photos exponentially faster, with far less power, which indicates to me that this is a software issue not hardware related.

Comment: Then you should include this & any other pertinent information in your question. It saves people wasting their time.

Comment: Why does the photo application contact anything and need to wait for timeout? Its opening a .png file stored on the local machine.

Comment: Windows Photo is an UWP App. I too have noticed it has some weird slowdowns. Sometimes photos show instantly, sometimes they fail to open at all for no aparent reason, even when that photo was opened from a local SSD, opened fine the first time, and then literally seconds later fail to open at all. This IMHO is a bug in the Windows Photo app. I'd suggest using something else.

Comment: @Tetsujin I've noticed weird issues with Windows Photo myself, see previous comment. I would honestly call this a weird bug in the app over anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check if the following methods were helpful.

Option 1

Locate photo in Start and open it. Then click the [...] icon in the upper right corner of the opened window, and select the [Settings] option. In the opened Setting window, turn off [People] in the [Viewing and editing].

Option 2

Click Start and type Calibrate Color to open Calibration Display Color, click [Next] in the opened display color calibration window until the final calibration is completed